# how to implement != in Google Analytics API using PHP?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics API to generate Google Analytics report.

I am implementing filters, in the filter, I want to make sure that,

```
ga:contentGroup2!=Answered;ga:pageviews!=0
```

here is my code,

```
$processing[1] = str_replace('filters=', '' , $e1_param_url[$i]); //, here $processing[1] will be ga:contentGroup2!=Answered;ga:pageviews!=0
                $e1_filters = explode(';' , $processing[1]);
                for($k_filters =0; $k_filters < count($e1_filters); $k_filters++){
                    $operator = '';
                    for($c_ops =0; $c_ops < count($operators); $c_ops++){

                        $operator = strpos($e1_filters[$k_filters],$operators[$c_ops]) != false ? $operators[$c_ops] : '';
                        if($operator != '') break;
                    }
                    $the_filter = explode($operator , $e1_filters[$k_filters]);

                    if(in_array($the_filter[0],$metrics)){
                        $metricFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_MetricFilter();
                        $metricFilter->setMetricName($the_filter[0]);
                        if(strpos('!',$operator)!= false) 
                            $metricFilter->setNot(true);
                        $metricFilter->setOperator($this->getOperator($operator));
                        $metricFilter->setComparisonValue($the_filter[1]);
                        array_push($metricFilters , $metricFilter);
                    }else{
                        $dimensionFilter = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
                        $dimensionFilter->setDimensionName($the_filter[0]);
                        if(strpos('!',$operator)!= false) 
                            $dimensionFilter->setNot(true);
                        $dimensionFilter->setOperator($this->getOperator($operator));
                        $dimensionFilter->setExpressions(array($the_filter[1]));
                        array_push($dimensionsFilters , $dimensionFilter);
                    }
                }
```

and here is my $this->getOperator function

```
    // get this list from: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Operator
function getOperator($operator){
    switch($operator){
        case '==':
            return 'EXACT';
        case '!=':
            return 'EXACT';
        case '>=':
            return 'NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN';
        case '<=':
            return 'NUMERIC_LESS_THAN';
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

so, in the case of != what should I return?

Answer (score 1):

According to the following [Google documentation for Metric Filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#metricfilter), it looks like your Metric Filter Operators are incorrect. Your `getOperator()` should look like this instead:

```
function getOperator($operator){
    switch($operator){
        case '==':
            return 'EQUAL';
        case '!=':
            return 'EQUAL';
        case '>=':
            return 'GREATER_THAN';
        case '<=':
            return 'LESS_THAN';
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

For the Dimension Filter, since your example is expecting a string comparison, it seems that you would only want `==` or `!=` and you can omit the `NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN` and `NUMERIC_LESS_THAN`. Therefore, you will always supply `EXACT` as the [Dimension Filter Operator](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Operator), and handle the `setNot()` value the same way you are currently.

So change this line of code:

```
$dimensionFilter->setOperator($this->getOperator($operator));
```

to this instead:

```
$dimensionFilter->setOperator('EXACT');
```

Comment: ga:contentGroup2!=Answered is my dimension filter, how do I choose operator for that?

Comment: I have updated my solution, please see if that works for the dimension filter and let me know.

Comment: It accepted values, but for some reason, it returns me 500 internal server error. And it says the error is at their end. So, I am investigating the issue.

Comment: Gotcha, hopefully you are able to get it working. If my solution answered your question, please accept it. Otherwise, let me know if there is anything else I can do to help!

Answer (score 0):

If using *Google Analytics ReportingV4*
you can set the expression directly
by

```
$filter = "ga:contentGroup2!=Answered;ga:pageviews!=0";
$ga_report_request->setFiltersExpression($filter);
```

check **Report Request Object** [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#reportrequest)